# Why I see different data between postgres DB running in docker and postico from main host?

Tags: postgresql, docker, postico

I am using docker container for postgres database, from UI which is powered from postgres. I deleted an entry from postgres via postico(client for postgres in mac), now when I see my database in postico is completely empty but when I refresh the UI, I still see the data!!!

Please correct me If I am postico is just the UI to see what is in the postgres running in the container, In that case I expected UI also to be empty but it is not the case.

Can someone tell me why my expectation is going wrong and please let me know if any info is needed?

Comment: See here for info on how to ask a good question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Hello! Could you add how you ran the container and how you deleted the database?

Comment: Best guess is you did not `commit` the query and it rolled back. You need to provide the actual commands you used. **Add as update to question**.